# Safely create and manipulate HTML in Ruby, without Rails

Tags: ruby, html

In Ruby, is there a library for creating HTML with the following characteristics:

- Is not dependent on, or a part of, Rails.
- All content is properly encoded, including attributes.
- Nodes are not immediately rendered into strings. That is, you can create a node, and then pass it to a method, append more nodes into it, or add and remove attributes. And then, sometime later, you can ask for the node to be rendered into HTML.

I am aware of the 'builder' and 'Nokogiri' libraries but they don't seem to be able to do all of the above.

There is a 'w3c-dom' library, which does do everything I want, but the DOM API is very low-level. Most libraries in other languages left the DOM API behind a long time ago.